# How do I read serial data from an arduino uno with batch on windows 10?

Tags: windows, batch-file, arduino

I'm trying, more specifically, to hibernate my computer with an infrared remote using **arduino**. I already have it set up so that the arduino registers the button on said infrared remote, and can then trigger an action. What I'm trying to code on my computer is a batch script that will constantly run and listen for serial data from the arduino. The theory is that when the arduino gets the infrared signal, it will blast a letter through serial, or 'o'. Then, the batch script on the computer will see that, and proceed to hibernate the computer. I have already tried

```
MODE COM6:9600,N,8,1 >NUL
type COM6 > sample.txt
```

to test whether or not windows could read the serial data, but the arduino just starting broadcasting a '1' for a tenth of a second every second. Once I ran this, and a text file was generated that was completely blank. Here is the arduino code:

```
  void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  Serial.write("Hello!");
  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: Why not coding a simple C/Python/Java program that run `shutdown` command? You have available lots of libraries for Arduino serial.

Comment: > _the arduino just stopped broadcasting once I ran this_ **Can't believe this** ;) Arduino will stop broacasting only when it loses power or you keep the reset button pressed.

Comment: @jabujavi I want to use a batch file as not to download other external programs like python and Java so I can keep it vanilla, and working with my other batch files.

Comment: @datafiddler you must've not understood what I'm saying. Whenever I run the batch script looking for the data, the transmit like blinks for about a tenth of a second then goes off, every second, while normally transmitting it is almost always on.

Comment: Which transmit line do you mean? On the arduino with that "hello" sketch @9600 you should see the TX pin blink very shortly (0.01s) every second. Independent of a windows bat job reading or not... )